# How many IPv4 addresses are used for dynamic assignment through ISPs?

Tags: ip, dhcp, ip-address

From the IPv4 addresses, we have the private addresses (10.x, 172.x, 192.x), localhost addresses (127.x), self-assigned (169.x) multicast and broadcast addresses.

From the remaining, I guess a lot of addresses are assigned to large companies, use for web servers etc.

How many IPv4 addresses (roughly) are used for dynamic assignment by ISPs to users for dial-in connections like DSL router etc.?

Comment: Millions.  What IPv4 addresses can be (a public address and assigned) is well documented, so your question, is sort of confusing

Comment: @Ramhound: millions, compared to 2^32 is just a few...

Comment: Hundreds of millions is still millions.  How about just improving the question?  2^32 cannot be public addresses, so your comment, isn't constructive

Comment: Some whois records indicate whether they are dynamic pools or not, but downloading the whole database and finding the right keywords and searching it would take ages to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISP's are just like large companies that are assigned IP addresses. They can decide how many of their customers have a dedicated IP address and how many have dynamic IP. For example in Romania you have to pay for static IP in most ISP's. Even ISP's that provide home connection of 1 GBPS do not give you static IP by default. So many customers can connect through the same IP at different times.

Here is a list with some companies that have been assigned IP addresses by IANA. In other countries is the same. There are some companies and ISPs that have IPs and than they assign them to customers statically or dynamically or sell them / rent them to other companies.

Comment: I agree. But not all of the large companies that have large blocks of IP addresses are ISPs.

Comment: That is correct. But it does not matter anyway. Some companies are ISPs. What is unclear ?

Comment: How many companies are ISPs and what blocks do they have? Did you want to provide a link on "Here is a list", maybe?

Comment: Here is a list with all the major IP blocks from Romania. Most of them are from ISPs http://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/ro.html

Comment: @ThomasWeller a list would make this question not on topic.

Comment: Here is a list with all the countries in the Nirsoft Database http://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/index.html and here is a list with the United States IP blocks (only blocks that contain more than 65 thousands addresses are included http://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/us.html Unfortunately for the US the companies are missing. But anyway the companies decide what IPs will be asigned dynamically and what IPs will be asigned otherwise, So it is impossible to know the exact answer to your question.

Answer (score -1):

Generally dynamically assigned IPs are private IPs, not publicly addressable.  Assigning public IPs for dialup users is not cost effective.  Public IPs are very valuable, private IPs are free.

Comment: They can't assign me a private IP address, because they don't know whether I use it in my network already.

Comment: They assigned it to you on their end......Lots of people can be given the same public address.

Comment: @ThomasWeller The private IP they give you and the private IPs you use are totally different

Comment: @ThomasWeller, seach for Carrier-Grade NAT (CGN). The RIRs are out of IPv4 addresses to assign to the ISPs, so the ISPs are hoarding thier public IP addresses for those willing to pay a premium to have a public IP address on their WANs. Many ISPs are now using CGN. There is a block of addresses set aside for this, but all the ISPs I see using CGN are using the same RFC 1918 address space that you may be using, too. This has caused more than a few problems with people needing to port forward or having address conflicts. This will be more common as time goes by.

Comment: Sorry to downvote, but this is just wrong.    While most computers in small offices use DHCP and NAT, an aweful lot of devices use dynamically assigned addresses - typically negotiated by PPP and Radius or equivalent - (and in fact, a lot of static IP's are dynamically assigned as well by looking up username or mac address, rather then being hard coded in any router).   I acknowledge that "Carrier Grade NAT" is becoming more common, but luckily its still not uniquitous)

Comment: @Keltari , I think you are making a confussion. Most ISPs assign public addresses dynamically BECAUSE like you said public IP addresses are valuable. They do not want to assign you a public IP and then not be able to assign it to someone else in case you do not use it. But every computer HAS to have a public IP address to be able to access websites and servers in the internet.